# LINQ select into array

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to modify a LINQ query to select some properties into an array but am struggling to achieve part of it.

```
    toRun.AddRange(entity.Properties
        .Select(property => property.PrimaryField)
        .Select(field => new { field, entity = entity.EntityName, table = field.Table, key = entity.EntityIdField })
```

I need this amending so that if a second property called SecondaryField is not null or empty string it will be added to the results of the first Select statement.

For example if entity.Properties contains:

```
    Property { PrimaryField = "a", SecondaryField = "b" },
    Property { PrimaryField = "c", SecondaryField = "" }
```

I would like the first Select statement to return:

```
    { "a", "b", "c" }
```

Appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: So you want a list of all PrimaryFields, and all SecondaryFields that are not empty or null?

Comment: Both your title and your question are unclear, and I don't really see the relation between the code blocks and the output, but are you looking for something like `.SelectMany(p => new[] { p.PrimaryField, p.SecondaryField).Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(p))`?

Comment: @CodeCaster That is what i was thinking.

Comment: Trying that out now thanks CodeCaster

Comment: I struggled to find a way to word the question well unfortunately

Comment: @CodeCaster Your example will also remove PrimaryField values that are null or empty and if that's what the OP wants, it's fine. The question, however, only mentions SecondaryFields that are null or empty.

Comment: @bixarrio I agree - okay in this case however as PrimaryField should never be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to reproduce what you want: you have a class with two properties:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

Of which you have a collection:

```
var foos = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Bar = "a", Baz = "b" },
    new Foo { Bar = "c", Baz = "" },
};
```

And from this collection, you want to select all properties that have a non-empty value into an array.

You can do so using `SelectMany()`:

```
var result = foos.SelectMany(f => new[] { f.Bar, f.Baz })
                 .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
                 .ToArray();
```

You select a new array containing the value of both properties, then filter out the values you don't want, and turn the result into an array again.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty simple - get both fields, use a `Where` to remove the null/empties and turn to an array:

```
 var result = entity.Properties.SelectMany(p =>new[]{ p.PrimaryField,p.SecondaryField})
            .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
            .ToArray();
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/MHM61977